# Typescript doesn't recognise the type

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm getting the error `Property 'width' does not exist on type '{ theme: BoxProps; }'` in VSCode and I'm not sure why. I'm new to typescript so i assume the issue is very simple.

```
type BoxProps = {
  width: string;
}

const Box = styled('div')<BoxProps>(({ theme, width }) => ({
  width: width || '100%'
}));
```

Comment: This [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicusage-material-demo-forked-bzp1y?file=/demo.tsx) demonstrates that this should work. What version of MUI and Typescript are you using and how are you importing `styled` in this file?

Comment: I was using MUI 4. This is where the problem came from.